# How to write child object extends parent class to ORC file

Tags: hive, orc

I have a child class extends parent class. I am writing child class objects to the orcfile. I have child class objects in a List. I am looping through the list and writing to orc file. The child class object has parent class variables also.

Class objectClass = Child.class

```
ObjectInspector inspector = ObjectInspectorFactory.getReflectionObjectInspector(objectClass, ObjectInspectorFactory.ObjectInspectorOptions.JAVA);
orcFileWriter = OrcFile.createWriter(fs, new Path(partPath), config, inspector, 67108864, CompressionKind.ZLIB, 10, 0);
```

I have observed the NULLvalues for the parent class variables. When I verify the child class object, I can see values for the parent class variables.